# About mouse controlling in c/c++ [ubuntu] gnome or kde??? probably

Tags: linux, x11, gnome, kde-plasma

Several questions about how to write a mouse controlling module in c/c++
Any comments are much appreciated.

I have a mobilephone which can connect to my ubuntu 11.04 laptop
through wireless network.
I installed a putty for nokia symbian s60 v3.

With putty, I can execute commands such like mplayer in order to play
music when i am in my bed.

The problem is putty cannot controll mouse directly.

I am thinking if I can write a program who receives arrow keys signals
from my putty and move the mouse from my desktop.
Then I can control my laptop when I am doing a presentation through my
mobile-phone.

If anyone knows how to deal with it, please give me some advices.
Where should i get started?  which c/c++ header/libs that i have to use.
Any websites or online mannual that i should take a look at.

I am running unity (based on gnome 2.3. right?)

Thanks.
Guannan

Comment: Um, ever think of building a web interface?

Comment: +1 for programming to avoid getting out of bed.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually not simple on linux/X window system, but it can be done.  Probably one of the following would be your answer:

- set up xtest so that you can inject mouse events into the window system
- tell the window manager to take input from a "fake mouse" of some sort - maybe you can tell it that a named pipe or even pty is a serial mouse?
- make or find a kernel driver giving you another mouse entry under /dev/input to which you can push mouse events from some other program